# Farm/Cropland data

Tags: agriculture, land

Been looking through [this](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?groups=agriculture8571&page=12) but haven't found anything related to *shapefiles mapped to crops on land*. In particular I am wondering if there is data on the plots of land mapped to the specific crops on the land, down to the scale of a county/town/village *across the world*. If not, what the major sources are and where the specific / detailed town-by-town ones would be if there's not a central source like the USGS or USDA (like if I should just look at the nation websites for each place, or whatnot).

Other searches I've done:

- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?metadata_type=geospatial&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435618%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453146&q=farm&res_format=ZIP&res_format=CSV&ext_bbox=&sort=views_recent+desc&ext_location=
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=crop&sort=views_recent+desc&res_format=ZIP&res_format=CSV&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-97.119140625%2C7.667441482726068%2C-86.748046875%2C16.25686733062344

[This](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b7ba5c49e50d4b1fbfcb4e33a0cecf1a) looks like one small piece, but just for a specific year and place, and I don't think it's free/open.

Comment: i thought this was a duplicate question on here, but you specifically requested .shp/geo data so i don't think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Census of Agriculture (Ag Census)](https://www.nass.usda.gov/AgCensus/index.php) has this [data](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Publications/AgCensus/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Census_Web_Maps/Data_download/index.php), but you are going to have to put it together.
It goes down to FIPS Code level, so basically localities, and you'll need [County Level data](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Publications/AgCensus/2012/Full_Report/Volume_1,_Chapter_2_County_Level/), plus the [shapefiles](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Publications/AgCensus/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Atlas_Maps/).